# My new LG 4k display port monitor does not show boot/login screens, but works once boot completed using other monitor

Tags: nvidia, multiple-monitors

I have Phenom based desktop on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS. I have upgraded the graphic card to Nvidia Quadro K420 (driver: Nvidia 340.98) and monitor to LG 4k. But the computer does not boot with this monitor connected through DP. I have to use an old Dell U2311H connected through DVI to boot and log in, then I need to go to set-up, to choose an option "both monitors display the same screen" and then I am able to switch off Dell monitor and work on the new LG, provided I don't use higher than full HD resolution. This is just nightmare for non-professional Ubuntu user. Any clue?